# data-val-regex-pattern is not working to negate some specfic characters

Tags: html, regex

I am developing a view using `html5`, I want to validate a `VIN` `field` with some particular regex pattern,

So I used `data-val-regex-pattern` to achieve this.

My validation is to not allow the user to enter `i,o,q,I,O,Q` he can enter anything in `a-zA-Z0-9`
So I have written the regex as `^[a-zA-Z0-9&&[^iIoOqQ]]$`this regex is not working.

Not working mean when ever I enter `ghtygfrt9090` it is saying invalid.
Below is the code:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="17" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9&amp;&amp;[^iIoOqQ]]$" data-val-regex="VIN is not valid">
```

Please help !!

Comment: I presume `data-val-regex-pattern` is parsed by some library or framework, rather than native browser functionality? Where does the regex get executed? I've never seen `&&` in a regex like that, but maybe it exists in some exotic flavour of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you tried `^[a-zA-Z0-9&&[^iIoOqQ]]$` does not have a quantifier for the character class and if supported will match only a single occurrence of the listed.

Repeating it would look like `^[a-zA-Z0-9&&[^iIoOqQ]]+$`

---

In some regex engines, you could use character class [intersection](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html) using `$$`

If it is not supported, you could make use of a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*[iIoOqQ])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lVE90g/1)

Another option is to update the ranges excluding the chars

```
^[a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jzXk7h/1)